# He wants to marry a blonde woman, and he hasn't found one/her - question about use of pronouns

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

Here is an interesting question about the use of pronouns.

I read a book that says a pronoun is used only when the speaker has already had the thing in mind to refer to. It says **Example 1** means he has a specific woman in his head already and that in **Example 2** he hasn't so that the word **one** is used.

**Example 1:**

> He wants to marry a blonde woman.
> And she is a nurse.

**Example 2:**

> He wants to marry a blonde woman.
> And He hasn't found **one** yet.

However, I came up with an example that defies what the book says.

**Example 3:**

> He wants to marry a blonde woman.
> And she has to be tall and works as a doctor.

In **Example 3**, he doesn't have a specific woman to reference to in his mind. He just lists the traits he wants, and the word **she** is used here without problems.

Maybe the **she** refers to the type of woman he likes or the ideal woman in his head so what the book says is still valid?

Comment: You use the proniun to substitute a **noun**  that you already mentioned. A: *I'm going to go to university* B: *Which **one**?* [Which university?] A: *The **one** [university] that my dad went to*. B: *Edinburgh? That **one**?*

Comment: In your 3rd example, *woman* could be substituted with *one* "He wants to marry a blonde woman, **a  tall one** who is also a doctor."

Comment: Your sentences are misusing conjunctions. There is no reason to start the sentence with And as you have unless you're writing dialog. Each sentence should be "...woman, and..."

Comment: @FeliniusRex Thank you for that. Would you answer my question regarding the use of pronouns?

Comment: @vincentlin I agree with what Mari-Lou A has said. She said it well, so I had nothing to say there.

Comment: Mary-Lou's comment on your third example hints at the answer.  It depends on how *one* is used.  You cannot say *and one has to be tall and work and as doctor.*  That usage doesn't work.  You have to say *A tall one that works as a doctor.*  Why?  That's tricky and I don't have an answer for you at this moment.  Maybe someone else knows off hand.

Comment: @EllieK Thanks for your reply. My confusion comes from what the book says. It says "one" is used when the speaker doesn't have a specific reference in mind. In other words, it is indefinite. A pronoun such as "he" or "she" is used when there is already a specific person in mind. However, my Example 3 also works, and it is not a definite reference but just some attributes or traits to narrow down the scope. Doesn't this prove the book I read is wrong? Or we can say in reality the language is flexible and does not always follow what books say. I would like to know what you think.

Comment: @vincentlin - The book provides an interesting insight, one that I had not considered before.  I cannot comment on its validity unless I think about it more.  My earlier comment was to point out that *one* could be used as a pronoun in your third example but the structure of the sentence would need to change for that to happen.  *He wants to marry a blonde woman, one that is tall and is a doctor.*

Comment: Thank you. It is also something I have never thought about before. Do you think both of Example 3 and my analysis of it are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He wants to marry a blonde woman. And she has to be tall and work as a doctor.

I find the use of **she** normal in your last example; its use in place of **one** suggests that he is imagining someone with some degree of specificity, which is borne out by the following description.

(Note that *works* is changed to *work*, agreeing with *has to be*.)